# Where are Documents Stored When Using Information Governance Retention

Tags: administration, retention, compliance-center

We've had several cases of users deleting files and support unable to restore them. So, to avoid losing sensitive data, we've setup a retention policy in the M365 Compliance center. There aren't many resources that match the new layout in the admin center so I was unable to find a location for retained documents.

Based on this screenshot, where are deleted documents stored / archived if a user deletes them from their site? Is there an additional step of setting up labels or will this store deleted documents in a special recycle bin?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the **Preservation Hold** library. It should be on the **top-level site of the site collection**. Most users can't view the Preservation Hold library because **it's visible only to site collection administrators**.

Details here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention-policies-sharepoint?view=o365-worldwide#how-retention-works-for-sharepoint-and-onedrive

Comment: It turns out we can't even delete site collections with Retention enabled. If we toggle it off temporarily, will the Preservation Hold Libraries be deleted?